# Rails partial looping through local_assigns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm populating a partial with many instance variables in the locals hash. Is there a way to pull multiple instance variables from local_assigns in the partial?

```
<%= render 'tabs', :locals => {:tab1 => @news, :tab2 => @people, :tab3 => @tags} %>
```

In the partial I'd like to create a dynamic set of tabs based on the number of instance variables I populate the locals with.

```
<% local_assigns.each do |local_assign| %>
  <% local_assign.each do |tabs| %>
     <!-- Grab tab class name -->
     <li class="tab"><%= tabs[:class] %></li>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Vimsha I ended up using collection instead of locals and created the instance variable in the controller.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

```
Controller
@tabs = [@news, @people]

View
<%= render 'tabs', :collection => @tabs %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pass it as an array

```
render 'tabs', :locals => {:tabs => [@news, @people, @tags]} %>
```

in your view

```
<% tabs.each do |tab| %>
   <!-- Grab tab class name -->
   <li class="tab"><%= tab[:class] %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `<%= tabs[:class] %>`